# Swift SHA256 encryption returns different encrypted string compare to Objective C

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, encryption, sha256

I am migrating some codes from objective c to swift. I want to encrypt a string with a key using SHA 256 algorithm in swift. But comparing to Objective C implementation swift code returns different encrypted string. Both codes looks same only the syntax is different. Can someone help me get the same result in swift as I used to get in Objective C? Below are the code samples from both languages.

Objective C:

```
NSString* key = @"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
const char *cKey = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [@"message" cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *hash = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
 NSString* encryptedString = hash.base64Encoding;
```

Swift:

```
let key = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"
let cKey = key.cString(using: .ascii)!
let cData = "message".cString(using: .ascii)!
var digest = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), cKey, cKey.count, cData, cData.count, &digest)
let hash = Data(digest)
let encryptedString = hash.base64EncodedString()
```

Comment: What are the results you get in each case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `cKey` and `cData` include the terminating null character of the strings, and in the Swift version that is counted in `cKey.count` and `cData.count`, whereas in the Objective-C version `strlen(cKey)` and `strlen(cData)` do *not* count the terminating null character of the strings.

Doing

```
 CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), cKey, strlen(key), cData, strlen("message", &digest)
```

instead would fix the issue in your example, but is not safe for non-ASCII characters.

What I actually would do is to convert the strings to `Data` values (which do not include a terminating null byte) with the UTF-8 representation. Then pass the underlying byte buffers to the encryption method:

```
let key = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"
let cKey = Data(key.utf8)
let cData = Data("message".utf8)
var digest = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
cKey.withUnsafeBytes { keyPtr in
    cData.withUnsafeBytes { dataPtr in
    CCHmac(CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256), keyPtr.baseAddress, cKey.count, dataPtr.baseAddress, cData.count, &digest)
    }
}
let hash = Data(digest)
let encryptedString = hash.base64EncodedString()
```

This produces the same result `ZNjnsz2Uv5L0PvWIJjSh0BrOovuRXOSFWQ0s1Rd8VSM=` as your Objective-C code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This made my day. You are a genius!!