# Swift equivalent of hash_hmac in PHP

Tags: swift, hash, hmac, hmacsha1

I have been trying to create an oauth_signature in Swift4 which is to be sent and compared with the one already generated in the php backend code using hash_hmac function. I have used the below code to generate the signature, but the result I got is entirely different from the one generated by hash_hmac() in PHP.

```
func digestHMac256(key: String) -> String! {   

        let str = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let strLen = self.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
        let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>.allocate(capacity: digestLen)

        let keyStr = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let keyLen = key.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let algorithm = CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256)

        CCHmac(algorithm, keyStr!, keyLen, str!, strLen, result)

        let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: result, length: digestLen)

        let hash = data.base64EncodedString()

        return hash
    }
```

**This is my php code for signature generation**

```
$hash_algorithm = "sha1"; 

$string_to_sign = "GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fv1%2Fhomepage&customerid%3D1247";

$secret = "cs_a6twe79rt7aa";

$signature = base64_encode( hash_hmac( $hash_algorithm, $string_to_sign, $secret, true ) );
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: What result do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: My guess: It is the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56288759/1187415.

Comment: And please check [these related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+hash_hmac)

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for replying..still I didn't able to solve it..going through these answers

Answer (score 0):

In PHP code you are using SHA1 and in Swift code - SHA256. These are different hashing algorithms and that's why you're getting different signatures. You should use `kCCHmacAlgSHA1` instead.

Also you should avoid using `cString` API, it's not safe in Swift. It's better to use Data instead.

```
func digestHMac256(key: String) -> String! {

    guard
        let strData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),
        let keyData = key.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return ""
    }

    let digestLen = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<Any>.allocate(capacity: digestLen)

    let algorithm = CCHmacAlgorithm(kCCHmacAlgSHA256)

    strData.withUnsafeBytes { strBytes in
        keyData.withUnsafeBytes({ keyBytes in
            CCHmac(algorithm, keyBytes, keyData.count, strBytes, strData.count, result)
        })
    }

    let data = NSData(bytesNoCopy: result, length: digestLen)

    let hash = data.base64EncodedString()

    return hash
}
```

Also check the string which you're trying to encode. For example:

```
let toEncode = "GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fv1%2Fhomepage&customerid%3D1247"

let encoded = toEncode.digestHMac256(key: "cs_a6twe79rt7aa")
// dvU3NwZXqG31Sziagj3JgkUCLwTRxT3w733yRWzL7bM=
let encodedWithoutPercentEncoding = toEncode.removingPercentEncoding!.digestHMac256(key: "cs_a6twe79rt7aa")
// ZRmxmYPXZq/rLLkJsx1A/AtK7BarML7gu62+fYfzLvs=
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out..it really helped..but still I couldn't generate the required signature..they are again, different.